# Is there any workaround to rethrow an exception and preserve the stacktrace in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, exception

I know that Chrome has a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=60240) not preserving the stacktrace when rethrowing an exception in Javascript.

I have the following code running in Chrome:

```
try {
    try {
      runCodeThatMayThrowAnException();
    } catch (e) {
        // I'm handing the exception here (displaying a nice message or whatever)
        // Now I want to rethrow the exception
        throw (e);
    }
} catch (e) {
    // The stacktrace was lost here :(
}
```

Is there any way to keep the stacktrace? A jQuery plug-in maybe? Any workaround or ideas?

Comment: Can I know why you chose to have two try...catch?

Comment: First, because I need to display a nice message to the user in case one of the services are not available. Crashing is not an option.
Second, because I need to send the content of the javascript exception somewhere to my backend to know exactly what happened. Maybe it's a bug and I want to fix it before the customer calls me saying that the site is not working.

Comment: But why one level of try...catch is not enough? Is it because you want to aggregate all the error messages?

Comment: No it's because I'm adding more information to the exception. I don't want to end with an exception message saying: "value is NaN". I want to have a more descriptive exception like "The amount returned from the server for invoiceId 123 is equals to 'abc' and cannot be considered as a number."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the final catch block try

```
    throw e.stack;
```

And I mean the very last one (the one going to the browser). If you nest your try/catch deeper, you'd need to change your previous throws.

```
    function throwError() {
        var test = _undefined.propertyAccess;
    }
    try {
        try {
            try {
                throwError();
            } catch (e) {
                alert("exception: " + e.stack);
                throw e;
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e.stack);
            throw e;
        }
    } catch (e) {
        throw e.stack;
    }
```

What an odd bug.